# Why this Runtime exception occur in this code "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"?

Tags: java

Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at GFG.main(File.java:32)

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int t=sc.nextInt();
  while(t-- > 0)
  { 
   String str=sc.nextLine();
   char c='\n';
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
   {
    c=str.charAt(i);
    if(c>=97&&c<=122)
    {
     if(i==0)
      System.out.print((char)(c-32));
     else if(i!=0&&str.charAt(i+1)==' '&&str.charAt(i-1)==' ')
      System.out.print((char)(c-32));
     else if(i!=0&&str.charAt(i+1)!=' '&&str.charAt(i-1)==' ')
      System.out.print((char)(c-32));
     else
      System.out.print(c);
    }
    else
     System.out.print(c);
   }
          c=str.charAt(i);
   if(c>=97&&c<=122)
    System.out.println((char)(c-32));
   else
    System.out.println(c);
    
  }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its calling a place in string that does not exist with what it seems `str.charAt(i-1)` method call. When i == 0, or i == str.length-1 and call charAt(i+1). You can always put a break point and debug your application through IDE.

also Exception tells you it's location : GFG.main(File.java:32) thats 32nd line
Which is that line in the original file with all the imports, comments and package name?

Comment: but if i==0 first if will hold it never goes on other else condition so if i>0 this str.charAt(i-1) will right.

Comment: can you highlight which line is line no32?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `Scanner` class method. If you want to use `nextLine`  after `nextInt`, you have to fire one blank newline in your code like,

```
sc.nextLine();
```

Then the scanner will scan your `String str=sc.nextLine();`.

Coming to your exception, when the scanner will take input, it is taking as a blank string like "", so when your trying to find chatAt(0), which will trying to excess the value from the empty String.

So put the below code in your program,

```
sc.nextLine(); // just for scanner to skip this line
String str=sc.nextLine();
```

For more infor, you can refer this link [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)